# Select MAX from 2 tables

Tags: sql, db2

I have the following select and I would like to return only the most recent TranDate when the Tracct occurs more than once.

```
SELECT tracct, trancd, trnsta, date(digits(trdat7)) as TranDate, type 
FROM DATALIBRARY.LNHIST LNHIST 
JOIN DATALIBRARY.LNMAST LNMAST 
  on LNHIST.TRACCT = LNMAST.ACCTNO 
WHERE YEAR(date(digits(trdat7))) >= YEAR(current_date) - 2 and trnsta = '1' and trancd = 891 and type not like 'I%'
```

Current result:

```
|Tracct | Trancd | Trnsta | TranDate   | Type|
----------------------------------------------
 425660 | 891    | 1      | 2013-05-10 | C5  |
 102649 | 891    | 1      | 2013-05-10 | C5  |
 102741 | 891    | 1      | 2015-08-08 | RO  |
 102741 | 891    | 1      | 2015-09-10 | RO  |
 102741 | 891    | 1      | 2014-05-10 | RO  |
 115298 | 891    | 1      | 2013-03-31 | CV  |
 102313 | 891    | 1      | 2015-04-10 | CL  |
 102313 | 891    | 1      | 2015-05-10 | CL  |
```

Comment: What does the source data look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [nested query](http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/ibmdb2/w/wiki/6750.nested-table-expressions)

Call your query `SUBQUERY`.

I think you want

```
SELECT Tracct, Trancd, Trnsta, Type, MAX(TranDate)
FROM SUBQUERY
GROUP BY Tracct, Trancd, Trnsta, Type
```

Or you can rewrite your query to something like this

```
SELECT tracct, trancd, trnsta, type, MAX(date(digits(trdat7))) as TranDate 
FROM DATALIBRARY.LNHIST LNHIST 
JOIN DATALIBRARY.LNMAST LNMAST 
  on LNHIST.TRACCT = LNMAST.ACCTNO 
WHERE YEAR(date(digits(trdat7))) >= YEAR(current_date) - 2 and trnsta = '1' and trancd = 891 and type not like 'I%'
GROUP BY tracct, trancd, trnsta, type
```

Comment: Yes, I did the nested query first because the question didnt provide much detail on the schema and have to work on the premise your query work. Then I realize how could update your query. But if have chance take a look on the link is good reading.